# Positioning Seek bar between two textviews doesn't work

Tags: android

I have a seek bar positioned between two textviews,however it does not display as desired. Below is the XML

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/timerDisplay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <!-- Current Duration Label -->
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/songCurrentDurationLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="12.00"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:textColor="#eeeeee"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/songProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
        android:thumb="@drawable/seek_handler" />

    <!-- Total Duration Label -->
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/songTotalDurationLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="10.00"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:textColor="#04cbde"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

The above results to a view like
[image]

However this is the desired result
[image]

Where am I going wrong? I do not want to hardcode the seekbar's layout_width,what should be altered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use **android:weightSum**
and **android:layout_weight****

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/timerDisplay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <!-- Current Duration Label -->
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/songCurrentDurationLabel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="12.00"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:textColor="#eeeeee"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="10"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/songProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
        android:thumb="@drawable/seek_handler"
        android:layout_weight="80" />

    <!-- Total Duration Label -->
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/songTotalDurationLabel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="10.00"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:textColor="#04cbde"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="10"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/timerDisplay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <!-- Current Duration Label -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/songCurrentDurationLabel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight=".40"
        android:text="12.00"
        android:textColor="#eeeeee"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/songProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
        android:thumb="@drawable/seek_handler"  />

    <!-- Total Duration Label -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/songTotalDurationLabel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".40"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:text="10.00"
        android:textColor="#04cbde"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign following attributes to your seekbar.

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Here TextViews will wrap themselves and seekbar will take max width.